# IPC Message passing (windows)

Tags: c++, c, ipc, message-passing

I've started to learn Inter-process communication mechanisms. It seems that two the most popular are shared memory and message passing, but I can't find any tutorials how to use message passing in Windows. So is there such mechanism in Windows, if it is so can you please provide me with tutorial link?

FYI, I know that there're other more flexible mechanisms like pipes or sockets, but I also wanna learn message passing in Windows.

Comment: Message passing is no IPC mechanism by itself. You can implement a message passing protocol based on shared memory as well.

Comment: Maybe you are thinking of window messages? (SendMessage/PostMessage/GetMessage/etc)

Answer (score 1):

[The following IPC mechanisms are supported by Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/interprocess-communications):

- Clipboard
- COM
- Data Copy
- DDE
- File Mapping
- Mailslots
- Pipes
- RPC
- Windows Sockets

Comment: If you're into HPC you should have a look at MPI as well (https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface). It comes as a C++ library and is straight forward, robust and fast.