# Passing array of struct by reference

Tags: arrays, c, struct, pass-by-reference

I have to fork some children and keep track of some values when they fork off in an array of structures called PCB. I used a function named forker to fork off the children processes and within it am trying to modify the array of structs but when i print the entire struct after the fork function, its blank and full of zeros. The forker function keeps track of the total launched children and I am using that as my index for the array. Any ideas what I am doing wrong so that it wont save the values in my struct?

Forker Function

```
int forker(int totaltoLaunch, int simulLimit, int timeLimit,
           int totalLaunched, PCB *processTable)
{
    pid_t pid;
    if (totalLaunched == simulLimit) {
        return (totaltoLaunch);
    }
    else if (totaltoLaunch > 0)
    {
        if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
        {
            perror("fork");
        }
        else if (pid == 0)
        {
            processTable[totalLaunched].occupied = 1;
            processTable[totalLaunched].pid = pid;
            processTable[totalLaunched].startSeconds = 0;
            processTable[totalLaunched].startNano = 1;
            
            printf("I am a child and supposed to run %d seconds\n", timeLimit);
            exit(0);
        }
        else if (pid > 0)
        {
            forker(totaltoLaunch - 1, simulLimit, timeLimit,
                   totalLaunched + 1, processTable);
        }
    }
    else
        return (0);
}
```

This is how I created my Process Table `PCB processTable[20];`

Comment: "when i print the entire struct...." I don't see any code that prints it

Comment: You modify the child's `processTable`, but I presume you print the parent's `processTable`

Comment: Tip: Recursion makes no sense here. Use a loop.

Comment: Are you expecting changes made by a child to be visible to the parent?

Comment: Since it is passed by reference, would it not change a global structure? I used recursion because I am only supposed to launch so many children simultaneously and felt this was the best way to return how many were left to be launched

Answer (score 2):

The parent process should wait for the children run to `exit(0)` before printing the `processTable`.

1. add a variable to hold an exit status from the children.

   ```
   pid_t pid;
   int status;
   ```
2. in the parent process, call `waitpid()` to wait for the children `exit()`.

   ```
    forker(totaltoLaunch - 1, simulLimit, timeLimit, totalLaunched + 1, processTable);
    waitpid(pid, &status, WNOHANG);
   ```

reference: [waitpid()](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=functions-waitpid-wait-specific-child-process-end)

---

update with [IPC(inter-process communication)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication)

`fork()` creates new process and each process owns its private memory space. So, the pointer been passed into would be addressing to its private memory space instead of the parent's. That why the PCB struct is blank in the parent process.

While, threads in a process would share the same memory space.

A solution for exchange information between processes is IPC.

On Linux system, [mmap()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) and [shmget()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/shmget.2.html) would help exchanging information between processes. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19672778/trying-to-write-to-an-int-in-shared-memory-using-mmap-with-a-child-process) might be helpful.

For Windows system, there are [several methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72798400/6099871) to exchange data between processes. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16739533/windows-shared-memory-segments) might be helpful.

Comment: I have a nohang wait call after the function and the PCB struct is still blank. I thought since I was passing a pointer to the globally created structure, that the child process' changes would be visible by the parents

Comment: Then, the [IPC(interprocess communication)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) should be considered.